# Matching and setting object variable from a list to a different object list

Tags: java, foreach, collections, java-8, java-stream

Trying to figure out the best way to match an Objects variable that is in a list with a different type of Object Variable in a list. Once the match has been found I would like to set a different variable within that first Object to another Object variable it matched with. The best way to explain this would be like this:

I have a `List<Cat> cats` and cat has the variables id, size, breed, name, vetId and vetName.

I also have a `List<Vet> vets` and vets have variables id, address, phone and name.

The list of `cats` has a vetId but vetName is null, I need to somehow add the name from the `vets` list.

I need a quick and efficient way to do this. I'm not so skilled with new Java 8 stuff but i'm sure there will be a quick way of doing this with it.

Comment: Do you have tried anything?

Comment: Could you please show the two classes mentioned? I mean `Vet` and `Cat`... If you have tried anything, show that, too, please.

Comment: @deHaar The classes are straight forward. Though they do not make any sense since author does not seem tried anything.

Comment: @Stefza You're asking for a *quick and efficient way*. Can you post your **inefficient** way first? So the community could help guiding you.

Comment: @ETO are they straight forward? I don't see information about the attribute types and I would not use a simple `String` for an address, for example. What about the id? Is it an `int` or a `long` or even a `String`? But in general, you're right, could be done like that and no effort was shown.

Comment: @ETO I removed the code but basically I used a for loop within a for loop to check each Object and if (cat.getVetId() == vet.getId()) { cat.setVetName(vet.getName) }

Comment: @Stefza Okay, got it. Check my `java-8` solution below then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two lists `List<Cat> cats` and `List<Vet> vets`

You can achieve what you need using Stream API:

```
// Build map of (vetId -> vetName) pairs
Map<Long, String> vetMap = vets.stream().collect(toMap(Vet::getId, Vet::getName));
// Update cats with proper vet names
cats.forEach(cat -> cat.setVetName(vetMap.get(cat.getVetId())));
```

Comment: Good answer, went with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use maps.

```
public void setCatVetNames(Collection<Cat> cats, Collection<Vet> vets) {
    Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<>(vets.size());
    for (Vet vet : vets) map.put(vet.getId(), vet.getName());
    for (Cat cat : cats) cat.setVetName(map.get(cat.getVetId()));
}
```

The code should be fairly self-explanatory, but basically: create a mapping from vet IDs to vet names (I assume IDs are strings, if they are ints change to `Map<Integer, String>`), then populate the map, and use the map to set vet names for the cats.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple filter while streaming the `List<Vet>` for every `Cat`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create some sample data
    List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Vet> vets = new ArrayList<>();

    cats.add(new Cat(1, 25, "Persian", "Kitty", 123, ""));
    cats.add(new Cat(2, 25, "Persian", "Pussy", 321, ""));
    cats.add(new Cat(3, 150, "African Lion", "Simba", 231, ""));
    cats.add(new Cat(4, 160, "Indian Tigre", "Shir Khan", 213, ""));
    cats.add(new Cat(5, 120, "Pantera", "Pantera", 123, ""));

    vets.add(new Vet(123, "Somewhere Road 123", "555-SHOE", "Dr. Bundy"));
    vets.add(new Vet(321, "Vegas Boulevard 69", "216-WHITETIGERS", "Dr. Siegfried"));
    vets.add(new Vet(231, "Baker Street 150", "150-MORIARTY", "Dr. Watson"));
    vets.add(new Vet(213, "Mulholland Drive 1", "321-NOIDEA", "Dr. Lynch"));

    // find out the names of the vets for each cat:
    cats.forEach(cat -> {
        Vet v = vets.stream()
                // filter by id
                .filter(vet -> vet.getId() == cat.getVetId())
                // receive the first result
                .findFirst()
                // or set the result to null if no vet for the vetId of the cat was found
                .orElse(null);
        // check if v isn't null here, in this example it won't be, so I omitted the check...

        // then print the results
        System.out.println(cat.getName() + " gets its treatment from " + v.getName());
    });
}
```

> Please note that I had to guess the types of the class attributes in `Cat` and `Vet` because you did not mention them in your question.

Comment: This is what i'm looking for but the removing the `System.out.println()` and replacing it with `cat.setVetName(v.getName());`

Comment: This solution is not performant. In worst case it will be `O(n * m)` where `n` is number of cats and `m` is number of vets.